# How to generate statistics on article views last week

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I see on sites that they sometimes have a statistic showing how many views an article or downloads a file had over the last week.  I think download.com does something like this. I was wondering how they go about doing this.  Are they actually keeping track of every days downloads or am I missing something really basic?

Are they doing something like having three rows called total_downloads, last_week_downloads, this_week_downloads. Then every week, copying the value of this_week_downloads to last_week_downloads and then resetting this_week_downloads to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it, depending on what your trying to get out of the stats.

One way is to include a `visits` column on your table, then just increase that number by 1 each time that article's page is loaded.
This however isn't very good for giving the past weeks number of views. You can do this in 2 ways:

1) another column in your table doing the same as `visits`, but run a cron job to put it back to 0 every week.

2) create another table which holds `article_id`, `ip_address` and `timestamp`, you would insert a record each time someone visits the article, storing their IP address (allowing you to roughly get page views and unique page views), and of course the timestamp allows you to query for only a sub-set of those records. Note: using this method you could store more information for stats, but it does require a lot more server resources.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am think I am better off adding the column and just rotating as necessary to avoid making this too server intensive.

Comment: @John Tangale a single MySQL data can save every single click on a site by a handful of clients without sweating. Just make sure your table is non-blocking and you use something like `DELAYED` or `LOW_PRIORITY` to make sure than, under heavy stress your logging will not affect the server.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way you can do this is **associate a MySQL field** alongside your article on the database **and just increment it**.

Assuming you we're retreiving article 123 from your database you would have something like this on your code:

```
<?php
// this would increment the number of views
$sql = "UPDATE table SET count_field=count_field+1 WHERE id=123";
...
?>
```

Comment: Right...that's what I would do for getting total views, but not the previous weeks views.

Comment: @John Tangale look at Nick's answer. Depending on the amount of data you want to save you keep just a counter and rotate it every week or you save all hits on a specific table and then, depending on your site volume pull the data directly from there or pre-cache the data with a cron job... whatever suits you. Your logic is correct.